# at an earlier age than

Tags: ellipsis, time, comparative-constructions

Could one use

a. He'll graduate from college **earlier** than all of his relatives.

b. He'll graduate from college **sooner** than all of his relatives.

c. He'll graduate from college **before** all of his relatives.

d. He'll graduate from college **younger** than all of his relatives.

instead of

e. He'll graduate from college **at a younger age** than all of his relatives.

?

To me a-c would normally mean that he will graduate from college at an earlier time than his relatives.

Now I don't know if one could use those sentences if context made matters absolutely clear or not. (For instance, if we had 'than his father' instead of 'than all of his relatives').

(d) seems fine to me, but sounds informal.

Comment: The question is really: graduate younger, graduate earlier. Early is really for time. I would avoid both in your context. Before and at a younger age work.

Comment: You can use d instead of e. The rest have nothing to do with age.